# XSD to assert 2 values given the attribtues name

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to write an assertion in my XML Schema that checks that the value of  `param` with the attribute `name = "Max_measurement_value"`  should always be superior to the value of `param` with the attribute `name = "Min_measurement_value"`

**XML**

```
<SET>
  <PAGE>
    <OBJETS>
      <OBJET name="x">
        <PARAMS>
          <param name="Max_measurement_value" type="Real" libelle="Maximum measurement value">17.0000</param>
          <param name="Min_measurement_value" type="Real" libelle="Minimum measurement value">0.000000</param>
        </PARAMS>
      </OBJET>
      <OBJET name="y">
        <PARAMS>
          <param name="Max_measurement_value" type="Real" libelle="Maximum measurement value">25.0000</param>
          <param name="Min_measurement_value" type="Real" libelle="Minimum measurement value">2.000000</param>
        </PARAMS>
      </OBJET>
    <OBJETS>
  <PAGE>
<SET>
```

in my XSD, I am using CTA because I have other `param` that are not `FloatType`

```
<xs:alternative test="@name='Max_measurement_value'" type="FloatType" />
<xs:alternative test="@name='Min_measurement_value'" type="FloatType" />
```

And I have created a `complextype` to define the `param` attribtues

```
<xs:complexType name="FloatType">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:float">
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="libelle" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I am note sure how to do this `assert` on this one since I am kind of a beginner to xml/xsd.
Thank you for you help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have expected to see, on the declaration of the PARAMS element, something like

```
<xs:assert test='
  if (exists(param[@name="Min_measurement_value"])
       and exists(param[@name="Max_measurement_value"])) 
  then param[@name="Max_measurement_value"] ge    
       param[@name="Min_measurement_value"]
  else true()'/>
```

Comment: Might simplify `if A then B else true()` to `not(A) or B`.

Comment: The assertion was working perfectly until I tried a value which is greater then 99; is it normal ?

Comment: The assertion is supposed to use the typed value, which means that `ge` should be a numeric comparison. However I heard rumours that some schema processors get this wrong; it would therefore be safer to force a numeric comparison by using `xs:double(param[...]) ge xs:double(param[...])`